# Calcular recursivamente el mayor numero de minusculas de una lista de String

Tags: java, recursión

Estoy tratando de hallar la cadena con mayor número de minúsculas de una lista de forma recursiva. Por algún motivo no consigo encontrar más que errores de **`StackOverFlow`**. ¿Alguien sabría decirme qué está fallando? Creo estar cubriendo bien el caso base y demás:

```
public static String cadenaMayorMinusculasRecursivo (List<String> l, Integer mins, Integer i, String res) {
        if(l.size()==0) {
            return "La lista está vacía";
        }
        else if(i.equals(l.size()-1)) {
            return l.get(i);
        }
        else {
            mins = caracteresMinusculaStream(l.get(i)) > mins ? caracteresMinusculaStream(l.get(i)) : mins;
            res = caracteresMinusculaStream(l.get(i)) > mins ? l.get(i) : res;
            return cadenaMayorMinusculasRecursivo(l, mins, i++, res);
        }

    }
```

Los métodos hacen lo que su nombre indica, y las variables `mins` y `res` pretenden almacenar el número máximo de minúsculas hallado hasta el momento y la propia cadena con mayor número de minúsculas, respectivamente. Tengo la función instanciada tal que:

```
    System.out.println(cadenaMayorMinusculasRecursivo(lista, 0, 0, ""));
```

Se agradece de antemano cualquier ayuda prestada.

Comment: *Los métodos hacen lo que su nombre indica* <- Los métodos deberían tener verbos, diciendo qué hacen. Siento decirte que no entiendo lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tenes un problema al pasar `i++`. Esta pasando `i` y luego aumentando el valor de `i`.. proba pasar `++i` o `i+1`

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las indicaciones, en especial a @gbianchi. Eso resolvió el problema de `StackOverFLow`, ahora solo queda pulir la función para que haga lo que tiene que hacer.